Can I use dropdown metadata inside the condition on an IF components in whatsapp flow?
I'm trying WhatsApp flow and would like to show/hide a component according a dropdown metadada
This is an example of my dropdown data-source
"data": {               
     "LstOpt":{
          "type":"array",
          "items":{
               "type":"object",
               "properties":{
                    "id":{
                         "type":"string"
                    },
                    "title":{
                         "type":"string"
                    }
               }
          },
          "__example__":[
               {
                    "id":"1",
                    "title": "Option 1",
                    "metadata":"5"
                },
                {
                     "id":"3",
                     "title": "Option 2",
                     "metadata": "15"
                }
           ]
      }
}   

I would like to reference the metadata on a IF condition and show/hide a component according to this value.
Something like this:
{
     "type": "If",
     "condition": "(${form.dropdown_name.metadada} == '5')",
     "then": [
          {
               "type": "Dropdown",
               "name": "Greatfield",
               "label": "My great field",
               "required":true
          }
     ]
}

is this possible?
Thanks in advance
